# OpenERP modeling / views: related object inline

Tags: forms, view, model, odoo

I have installed the built in OpenERP 6.1 module crm.

As a result, I now have res.lead active and visible at "Sales->Opportunities".

I'd like to edit this object / view to show the partner's billing address.

Since I want to do this on the Opporunities form, there is already a partner_id.

Copying another module, I defined my new module like this:

```
class crm_lead(osv.osv):
    _name = _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    _columns = {
    'billing_address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner.address', 'Partner Billing Address', domain="[('partner_id','=',partner_id),('type','in',['invoice', 'default'])]"),
    }
```

And I changed my update_xml to:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_case_form_view_oppor">
        <field name="name">Opportunity form (inherit)</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <separator string="Details" position="replace" />
                <field name="description" position="replace">
                    <group colspan="2" col="4">
                        <separator colspan="4" string="Billing" />
                        <field widget="one2many_list" mode="form,tree" name="billing_address_id" colspan="4" nolabel="1" />
                    </group>
                    <group colspan="2" col="4">
                        <separator colspan="4" string="Details" />
                        <field name="description" nolabel="1" colspan="4" />
                    </group>
                </field>
            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```

The problem is that the related object shows all the related fields (as I'd guess would be expected). In particular, it shows the partner_id and company fields, which I'd like to hide since they should default to / inherit from this opportunity (or the linked partner).

How can I hide these fields? I can't simply add a bunch of 'related' fields, as there is potentially more than one billing address.

Thanks for the help!

---

Edit: To be clearer, an opportunity should only have a single chosen billing address, chosen from the partner's invoice / default addresses. It should be displayed inline to allow easy editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to [specify the view](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#specify-views-for-related-fields) for related fields like this. You can use the context like this:

```
<field 
    name="order_line" 
    colspan="4" 
    nolabel="1"
    context="{'form_view_ref': 'module.view_id', 'tree_view_ref': 'model.view_id'}"/>
```

You can also specify the whole view for the child record as a [subview](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_3.html#using-subviews) within the parent view like this:

```
    <!-- <=== order_line is a one2many field -->
    <field name="order_line" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
        <form>
            <field name="qty"/>
            ...
        </form>
        <tree>
            <field name="qty"/>
            ...
        </tree>
    </field>
```

Comment: I tried the second method (subviews) after writing the question, as it seems like exactly what I want. Indeed, the res_partner view uses subviews for this effect. However, copying it into my update_xml fails to work - I still get the same drop-down widget. I'll test with the first method soon. Are you sure OpenERP supports subviews in inherited view architectures?

Comment: I set a few breakpoints in field_views_get and have noticed that while the contents of my subview is evaluated in __view_look_dom_arch, it is not returned in the final form (just before toolbar calculation). Any ideas?

Comment: More testing indicates that the defined subfields (correctly?) show up as xfields['billing_address_id']['views']['form'] and xfields['billing_address_id']['views']['tree'], but the web client refuses to show them.

Comment: Further testing seems to blame the web client, which seems to not support subviews for many2one fields. Still looking into it.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be true. Would you consider this a bug? The web js never calls self.set_embedded_view. Thanks for the tip about subviews. Marking accepted since you're correct, but OpenERP is wrong.

Comment: That's strange, @CB. I usually use the GTK client, so I didn't know about the web client's problem with subviews. Does the web client use the subview you saw defined on res_partner?

Comment: Isn't `crm_lead.billing_address_id` a one2many field, @CB. ? I thought you were going to define a subview on that field. Where are you defining it? Does the res_partner view use the one2many_list widget?

Comment: I copied the definition of `crm_lead.billing_address_id` from `crm_lead.partner_address_id`, which is defined as `'partner_address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner.address',  ...`. 

The reason these are m2o fields is because they are asking the user to "pick one" - on other words, to make a foreign key on the `crm_lead` model.

`res_partner.addresses` is a `one2many` (as a partner can have many addressed), which is why the subview works. Both `billing_address_id` (mine) and `partner_address_id` (built in to crm) are many2one (choose one partner address from the domain), and thus fails.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `widget` attribute is inconsequential once an embedded view (subview) is in place. In addition, res_partner does not specify any widget attribute for it's address field.

Comment: Further, I cannot put make these fields a one2many as the requisite foreign key would not exist on the `res.partner.address` model. Assuming I added that to `res.partner.address`, this field would allow me to change the field type to one2many, which would allow the subview, but not allow the end user to make a "choice". Essentially I think i'd need to make a new OpenERP widget to allow my desired "edit inline, and choose one" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was a bit confused because you put a one2many widget on a many2one field.

If you want to control how a one2many field is displayed, use the subview or context methods I mentioned in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143997/4794).

If you want to control how a many2one field is displayed, you might be able to use related fields that pull fields from the record you selected, but I doubt it. Read-only might work, but I don't think it makes sense to edit multiple related fields and be able to change the selected record. You might be able to hack together some function fields with a store function that lets you write back to the related record, but it seems like it would really confuse your users.

Comment: Yeah, I can see why my initial question might be somewhat confusing. I think ultimately the 'cleanest' way to do it would be to create a new widget and form view (much like the existing one2many widget when it is in form mode) that would save the currently visible foreign object to the local many2one fk field in the DB, while also saving the remote related object. But, that doesn't seem exactly worth the effort right now :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes CB cleanest way to add New Widget tha twill be best way you can do it by your way. :)

Answer (score 0):

### On any OE Relation field you can define the Intenal View like  :

```
  <field name=""  mode="tree,form">
        <!--Internal tree view for your Relation field model-->
        <tree>
        </tree>

        <!--Internal Form view for your Relation field model-->
        <form>
        </form>
  </field>
```

Example Under Addons [1 Click to Example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/head:/marketing_campaign/marketing_campaign_view.xml#L271) [2 Click to See Example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/head:/marketing_campaign/marketing_campaign_view.xml#L287)

Hope this will help you,.

Comment: Thanks, using subviews was already mentioned by Don Kirkby, and these examples are also on one2many fields, not a many2one field, so it doesn't solve my new problem.

Comment: ok CB got he point, in m2o field you want to show the some values as per your chouce

Answer (score 0):

Now if yo uwan to shoe specific detail on your m2o file then we have some optional way also where you have to over the `def name_get` of your relational model, namge get look like :

```
name_get(cr, user, ids, context=None)
   Returns the preferred display value (text representation) for the records with 
   the given ids. By default this will be the value of the name column, unless the
   model implements a custom behavior. Can sometimes be seen as the inverse function
   of name_search(), but it is not guaranteed to be.

   Rtype :  list(tuple)
   Return : list of pairs (id,text_repr) for all records with the given ids.
```

So here in this method you can decide what string you want to show your relational field.
[Example](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py#L40)

This will fix your problem partially i guess.