# Accessing child value of many2one field in view

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

In order to be able to select a batch/lot more easily according to minimum life time requirements, I would like to have the value of the variable use_date (of module product.expiry) displayed next to the batch number in the view 'stock.view_pack_operation_lot_form'.

The view (belonging to the model stock.pack.operation) is defined as follows (default):

```
<record id="view_pack_operation_lot_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<!-- ... -->
    <field name="pack_lot_ids" nolabel="1" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'done')]}">
        <tree editable="bottom" decoration-success="qty_todo==qty"
              decoration-danger="(qty_todo &gt; 0) and (qty&gt;qty_todo)">
            <field name="lot_name" invisible="not context.get('only_create', False)"/>
            <field name="lot_id" invisible="context.get('only_create', False)"
                   domain="[('product_id','=', parent.product_id)]"
                   context="{'default_product_id': parent.product_id, 'active_pack_operation': parent.id}"/>
            <field name="qty_todo"
                   invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('serial') or context.get('state_done')"
                   readonly="1"/>
            <field name="qty" invisible="context.get('serial')"/>
            <button name="do_minus" type="object" icon="fa-minus-square" attrs="{'invisible': [('qty', '&lt;=', 0.99)]}"
                    invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('state_done')"/>
            <button name="do_plus" type="object" icon="fa-plus-square" attrs="{'invisible': [('plus_visible', '=', False)]}"
                    invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('state_done')"/>
            <field name="plus_visible" invisible="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
<!-- ... -->
</record>
```

The field *pack_lot_ids* is defined as One2many with reference to 'stock.pack.operation.lot' in the model 'stock.pack.operation'.
'stock.pack.operation.lot' has a field *lot_id* which is defined as Many2one with a reference to 'stock.production.lot'. 'stock.production.lot' contains the field *use_date* which I want to add to the view.

My first attempt was to add the field in dot notation as follows "reference.field_name":

```
<record id="stock_pack_operation_lots_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">stock.pack.operation.lots.form.inherit</field>
   <field name="model">stock.pack.operation</field>
   <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_pack_operation_lot_form"/>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <field name="lot_id" position="after">
          <field name="lot_id.use_date"/>
       </field>
   </field>
</record>
```

Which caused the following error:

```
Error context:
View `stock.pack.operation.lots.form`
[View_id: 722, xml_id: stock.view_pack_operation_lot_form, model: stock.pack.operation, parent_id: n / a]
```

I then found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35430803/5818622) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143997/5818622) post on SO suggesting a definition as subview:

```
<!-- ... -->
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="lot_id" position="after">
        <field name="lot_id" nolabel="1">
            <tree>
                <field name="use_date"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </field>
</field>
<!-- ... -->
```

This time it didn't throw an error, but instead of the field *use_date* it added the field *lot_id* a second time.

Any hint of how to add the *use_date* field next to the batch number is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a related field in the model stock.pack.operation.lot:

```
use_date = fields.Char(string='Use date', related='lot_id.use_date')
```

and then you could add it to your view:

```
<!-- ... -->
    <field name="pack_lot_ids" nolabel="1" attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'done')]}">
        <tree editable="bottom" decoration-success="qty_todo==qty"
              decoration-danger="(qty_todo &gt; 0) and (qty&gt;qty_todo)">
            <field name="lot_name" invisible="not context.get('only_create', False)"/>
            <field name="lot_id" invisible="context.get('only_create', False)"
                   domain="[('product_id','=', parent.product_id)]"
                   context="{'default_product_id': parent.product_id, 'active_pack_operation': parent.id}"/>
            <field name="use_date" />
            <field name="qty_todo"
                   invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('serial') or context.get('state_done')"
                   readonly="1"/>
            <field name="qty" invisible="context.get('serial')"/>
            <button name="do_minus" type="object" icon="fa-minus-square" attrs="{'invisible': [('qty', '&lt;=', 0.99)]}"
                    invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('state_done')"/>
            <button name="do_plus" type="object" icon="fa-plus-square" attrs="{'invisible': [('plus_visible', '=', False)]}"
                    invisible="not context.get('show_reserved') or context.get('state_done')"/>
            <field name="plus_visible" invisible="1"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
<!-- ... -->
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks @Dayana, in the meantime, I've also opted for a related field like you suggest - however, use_date is a Datetime field, hence it should be use_date = fields.Datetime(...). ;)
Since Odoo is quite new to me and I'm still learning how it works 'behind the scenes', I'm nevertheless interested in a solution of displaying use_date without modifying a model. Until now, I assumed that one can follow relations without limitation in a view and thus display the data of related models without changing the model the view is assigned to. Do you know whether my assumption is wrong?

Comment: On views you can't access fields using dot notation. You need to create fields in models or you must create related fields in order to show them on views. I hope your doubts are cleared up.